# Trying to join array of strings, such that they occur in next line using FTL template

Tags: html, arrays, string, freemarker, separator

Here is array of strings, myArray = ["green","blue","red"], I want to display each value in next line on html page
"green"
"blue"
"red"

I tried something like below but didnt work.

${myArray?join("\r\n")}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show each element on a new line using FTL template you can use the <#list> and 
 tag for new line. Here is my code:

```
<#list myArray as item>
  ${item}<br>
</#list>
```